# How to stop recaptcha to reload when page load again

Tags: recaptcha

I am using recaptcha in my registration page. When registration page load again my recaptcha image change it also reload. My question is how can I stop recaptcha to reload again (for new image) when my registration page reload.

Thanks in advance.
Dip

Answer (score 0):

Remove following code in your java script

```
Recaptcha.reload();
```